# IPsec VPN server with content filtering

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I have created an IPsec VPN server and I have implemented an IOS client to connect to it, everything is working well in both sides.

Now I wanted to add a content filtering in order to filter out some URLs ( like ads providers URLs...), I have tried to implement this on the client side using iOS programming but this needs some special entitlements to be granted from Apple.

So I want to ask if it is possible to implement this in the VPN server? does IPsec provide some similar functionality in it's config?

Please let me know if I'am in the wrong path I'm new to VPNs and my understanding are limited.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general content filtering is not a native functionality of IPSec VPN. If you are using route based IPSec VPN, then there is a visible network interface created on OS level and you can add an engine which will do that along with the VPN. Such engine can be SQUID, SNORT or alike. Here you need to ask yourself what is the purpose of what you are doing: is that parental control or intrusion protection or anything else and according to the answer choose proper engine to add on top of VPN.